# Increase speed of serialport when sending byte for byte

Tags: c#, serial-port

In the code below this text i have a problem.
This is a piece of code that sends byte's over an comport.
But with the first version of the program (That was written in C++ and not by me) the sending of the bootfile happens in 5sec. 
In the version that i have made it sends the bootfile in 46 sec witch is 9 times more.

Does anyone now how i can incease the speed or is it just an problem within .net 4

```
using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using Idento.Common.Tracing;
    using Idento.Common.Utilities;
    using System;

    namespace Communication
    {
        public class FileTransfer
        {
            private readonly String _bootFileName;
            private readonly String _appFileName;

            public int BootFilePercentage { get; private set; }
            public int AppFilePercentage { get; private set; }

            private BackgroundWorker _worker;
            private FileTransferDialog _dialog;
            private ComPort _comPort;
            private readonly string _port;
            private readonly string _baudRate;

            public bool Success { get; private set; }

            public bool _abort;
            public bool _aborted;
            public bool _sendingboot;


            public FileTransfer(string port, String baudRate, String bootFileName, String appFileName)
            {
                _port = port;
                _baudRate = baudRate;
                _bootFileName = bootFileName;
                _appFileName = appFileName;
            }

            public void Run()
            {
                _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
                _dialog = new FileTransferDialog(_worker, this);

                _worker.DoWork += Worker;
                _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += BackgroundWorkerCompletedEvent;
                _worker.RunWorkerAsync();

                _dialog.ShowDialog();
            }

            public void Abort()
            {
                _abort = true;

            }

            private void BackgroundWorkerCompletedEvent(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                // When an exception is generated in the worker we get a new exception here
                Object result;
                try
                {
                    result = e.Result;
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Sending files failed: " + exc.InnerException.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                    _dialog.Close();
                    return;
                }

                if (_aborted)
                    MessageBox.Show("Sending files aborted, Reset programmer.", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                else if (Success)
                    MessageBox.Show("Bootfile and Applicationfile are send succesfully.", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                else if (_comPort == null)
                    MessageBox.Show("Programmer not found at port " + _port, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Sending files failed: ", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                _dialog.Close();
            }

            public void Worker(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs doWorkEventArgs)
            {
                Success = false;
                _abort = false;
                _aborted = false;
                _sendingboot = true;
                try
                {
                    _comPort = new ComPort(_port, Int32.Parse(_baudRate));

                    // Synchronize baudrate with programmer
                    {
                        int answer = -1;
                        int count = 0;
                        do
                        {
                            _comPort.WriteByte(0);
                            answer = _comPort.ReadByte(50);
                            if (++count > 100)
                                throw new Exception("Synchronizing baudrate failed (1)");
                        } while (answer != 0);

                        _comPort.WriteByte(0x55);
                        if (_comPort.ReadByte(200) != 0xaa)
                            throw new Exception("Synchronizing baudrate failed (2).");
                    }
                    if (!_sendingboot)
                    {

                    }


                    SendBootFile();

                    if (!_aborted)
                    {
                        _comPort.Clear();

                        _comPort.WriteLine("#program");
                        if (_comPort.ReadByte(200) != 0x06)
                            throw new Exception("Login failed.");

                        // version number
                        for (int x = 0; x < 6; ++x)
                            if (_comPort.ReadByte(200) == -1)
                                throw new Exception("Retrieving version number failed.");

                        _comPort.Clear();


                        SendApplicationFile();

                        Success = true;
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                    Success = false;
                    throw new Exception("Communication error");
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    // MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString());
                    Success = false;
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (_comPort != null)
                        _comPort.Close();
                }
            }

            private void SendBootFile()
            {
                // NanoTimer timer = new NanoTimer();
                // String result = "";
                byte[] array;

                try
                {
                    array = File.ReadAllBytes(_bootFileName);
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Error reading boot file");
                }

                byte hiByte = (byte)(array.Length / 256);
                byte lowByte = (byte)(array.Length % 256);

                _comPort.WriteByte(hiByte);
                _comPort.ReadByte(100);
                _comPort.WriteByte(lowByte);
                _comPort.ReadByte(100);
                int count = 0;
                foreach (byte currentByte in array)
                {
                    if (_abort)
                    {
                        _aborted = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    ++count;
                    // NanoTimer timer = new NanoTimer();
                    _comPort.WriteByte(currentByte);
                    // Thread.Sleep( 1 );
                    // double time1 = timer.GetMilliseconds();
                    // timer.Reset();

                    if (_comPort.ReadByte(100) != currentByte)
                        throw new Exception("Error sending boot file (1).");
                    // double time2 = timer.GetMilliseconds();


                    if (count % 30 == 0 && _worker != null)
                    {
                        BootFilePercentage = count * 100 / array.Length;
                        _worker.ReportProgress(BootFilePercentage);
                    }
                }

                _comPort.Clear();

                if (!_aborted)
                {
                    if (_worker != null)
                    {
                        BootFilePercentage = 100;
                        _worker.ReportProgress(BootFilePercentage);
                    }

                    // Wait for acknowledge, takes more than 5 seconds
                    int answer = _comPort.ReadByte(20000);
                    if (answer != 0xaa)
                        throw new Exception("Error sending boot file (2).");
                }
            }

            private void SendApplicationFile()
            {
                // NanoTimer timer = new NanoTimer();
                StringList list;
                // Read file and put it in a list that will be sorted.
                try
                {
                    list = new StringList().FromFile(_appFileName);
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Error reading application file.");
                }
                list.Sort(new SRecordCompare());
                /*
                StringList testList = new StringList(list.Count);
                foreach (var item in list)
                    testList.Add(item.Substring(0, 4) + " " + item.Substring(4, 4) + " " + item.Substring(8));
                testList.ToFile("test.txt");
                 */

                int count = 0;
                foreach (String line in list)
                {
                    if (_abort)
                    {
                        _aborted = true;
                        break;
                    }

                    if (!line.StartsWith("S"))
                        continue;

                    ++count;
                    // _comPort.WriteLine(line.StartsWith("S9") ? "S9030000FC" : line);
                    _comPort.WriteLine(line);
                    // Thread.Sleep(10);

                    // wait for ACK
                    int answer = _comPort.ReadByte(2000);
                    if (answer == -1)
                        throw new Exception("Timeout waiting for ACK or NAK");
                    if (answer == 0x15)
                        throw new Exception("NAK received");
                    if (answer != 0x06)
                        throw new Exception(String.Format("Unknown byte {0} received", answer));
                    if (count % 30 == 0 && _worker != null)
                    {
                        AppFilePercentage = count * 100 / list.Count;
                        _worker.ReportProgress(AppFilePercentage);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

**Edit**
The sending of the bootfile happens here:

```
private void SendBootFile()
        {
            // NanoTimer timer = new NanoTimer();
            // String result = "";
            byte[] array;

            try
            {
                array = File.ReadAllBytes(_bootFileName);
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error reading boot file");
            }

            byte hiByte = (byte)(array.Length / 256);
            byte lowByte = (byte)(array.Length % 256);

            _comPort.WriteByte(hiByte);
            _comPort.ReadByte(100);
            _comPort.WriteByte(lowByte);
            _comPort.ReadByte(100);
            int count = 0;
            foreach (byte currentByte in array)
            {
                if (_abort)
                {
                    _aborted = true;
                    break;
                }
                ++count;
                // NanoTimer timer = new NanoTimer();
                _comPort.WriteByte(currentByte);
                // Thread.Sleep( 1 );
                // double time1 = timer.GetMilliseconds();
                // timer.Reset();

                if (_comPort.ReadByte(100) != currentByte)
                    throw new Exception("Error sending boot file (1).");
                // double time2 = timer.GetMilliseconds();


                if (count % 30 == 0 && _worker != null)
                {
                    BootFilePercentage = count * 100 / array.Length;
                    _worker.ReportProgress(BootFilePercentage);
                }
            }
```

**Edit II**
This is the Comport.cs class that i have maybe you can help me a little more when you see this.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace Communication
{
    public class ComPort
    {
        private readonly SerialPort _serialPort;

        public ComPort(string portName, int baudRate)
        {
            _serialPort = new SerialPort();

            _serialPort.PortName = portName;
            _serialPort.BaudRate = baudRate;

            _serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            _serialPort.DataBits = 8;
            _serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;

            _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            _serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
            _serialPort.RtsEnable = true;

            // _serialPort.WriteBufferSize = 1;

            _serialPort.Open();

            _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 20000;
            _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 20000;
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            while (ReadByte() != -1)
                continue;
        }

        private byte[] _array = new byte[] {0};

        public void WriteByte(byte value)
        {
            _array[0] = value;
            _serialPort.Write(_array, 0, 1);
            // _serialPort.BaseStream.WriteByte(value);
            _serialPort.BaseStream.Flush();
        }

        public void WriteBytes(byte[] array)
        {
            _serialPort.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
        }

        private int _readTimeOut = -1;

        public int ReadByte(int timeOut = 200)
        {
            if (timeOut != _readTimeOut)
              _serialPort.ReadTimeout = _readTimeOut = timeOut;
            try
            {
                //return _serialPort.BaseStream.ReadByte();
                return _serialPort.ReadByte();
                // _serialPort.Read(array, 0, 1);
                // return array[0];
            }
            catch (TimeoutException)
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// sends string followed by CR - LF
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="line"></param>
        public void WriteLine(String line)
        {
            WriteBytes(StringToBytes(line + "\r\n"));
        }

        public static byte[] StringToBytes(string input)
        {
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            try
            {
                _serialPort.Close();
            }
            catch(IOException)
            {

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You can just use _comPort.Write(array, 0, array.Length).  The odds that this makes any difference are very low.  Hard to guess what _comPort.Clear() might do but it can't be anything good.

Comment: What baud rate is it negotiating for transmission? That tends to be the biggest factor when your dealing with serial communication issues of speed.

Comment: @HansPassant _comPort.Clear make the comport clear and ready to pas trough files

Comment: Im using 19k 2 baudrate because it is an xp PC. That works just fine and it is not making the speed just like i want it to, i think it has to do with the timeout before szending out the bytes. but when i turn that of it wil not be as secure as i want. if i do that i could be that it wont pass all the bytes trough

Comment: Your bottleneck is that you're writing and synchronously reading one byte at a time. That flush and synchronous `ReadByte` are killing you.

Comment: I think that most of time this code waits on _comPort.ReadByte in the loop. In native code I usually set input buffer size to 1 to cause ReadFile return immediately, when one byte is received. Try to reproduce this trick by setting SerialPort.ReadBufferSize to 1. This is only my guess, I have never try this with .NET SerialPort.

Comment: @AlexFarber I will try that maybe that will work, thanks for the explaining so good.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments, i figures it out why its so slow. Nog its running on the speed that i want it to. There is an timeout with the serialport class of c#. This means that between writing the byte and reading the byte there will be an timeout of 15 ms. This is when you send the bytes. What we have tried is sending byte in groups of 100 instead of groups of 1 and increased the time. Its now 9 times so fast